# How to change an event handler callback dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, callback, serial-port

I've a serial port communication class which has the following code inside (among others but only the relevant part is shown):

```
public Form1 m_parent;
private delegate void ProcessPacketDelegate(byte[] packet);
public SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();

//Constructor code
....setting baudrate, portname etc.
... setting m_parent as the main form
...setting other things

//add an event handler
comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);
//constructor code end

void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
        comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
        comPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        m_parent.Invoke(new ProcessPacketDelegate(m_parent.ProcessPacket), comBuffer);
}
```

I'm instantiate this class from my main form, which address is stored in m_parent. The main form has a method called ProcessPacket, which processes the incoming packet. So far so good.

Now, I want to handle 2 serial ports so I need 2 instances of this class. However, I don't want them to use the same ProcessPacket method which could lead to packet collisions. I'd like to modify the serial port communication class in such way that in the constructor or by getsets I'd set callback method dynamically so instance #1 would invoke m_parentProcessPacket_A, instance #2 would invoke m_parentProcessPacket_B. Unfortunately this seems to be beyond my .NET skills, so any help would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Two serial ports == two DataReceived events.  Just move common code into a private helper method.  Btw, *never* call DiscardInBuffer() in a data reading method, that just causes undiagnosable data loss.

Comment: Do you mean that DiscardInBuffer can flush the buffer while the previous code line - comPort.Read(...) - hasn't finished yet?

Comment: The driver runs asynchronous from your event handler.  You'll discard bytes received a nanosecond after the Read call.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable in constructor and use that.

```
if(condition)
   handler =  comPort_DataReceived;
else
   handler =  comPort_SomeElseMethod;
```

And then bind this

```
comPort.DataReceived += handler
```

Comment: Thank you! Not really what I'm looking for but a great workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Have a constructor like that:

```
YourClass(ProcessPacketDelegate process_packet)
{
    // ...
    this.process_packet = process_packet;
}
```

In your class, have also:

```
ProcessPacketDelegate process_packet;
```

Then in your `comPort_DataReceived` do:

```
m_parent.Invoke(this.process_packet, comBuffer);
```

In you main form when your instantiating your class do:

```
instance1 = new YourClass(new ProcessPacketDelegate(this.ProcessPacket_A));
instance2 = new YourClass(new ProcessPacketDelegate(this.ProcessPacket_B));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I modified my class the way you suggested but stuck at the main form since in the line below the Intellisense found an error like:'the field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic filed, method...'

instance1 = new YourClass(new ProcessPacketDelegate(ProcessPacket_A));

Tried to put 'public delegate void ProcessPacketDelegate(byte[] packet);' line above but to no avail.